# Как заменить элементы списка со словами разделёнными пробелом и этими словами как новыми элементами?

Tags: python-3.x, list, split

Есть список списков:

```
[['y58u ufgh','ko9u','ffs5 dfdg'],
['rf32', 'sff4 sdfs re3d']
['df31 ytrd r546', 'erdr', 'ewr4 ljty']]
```

Подскажите, как разбить элементы, чтобы получился следующий результат:

```
[['y58u', 'ufgh', 'ko9u', 'ffs5', 'dfdg'],
['rf32', 'sff4', 'sdfs', 're3d'],
['df31', 'ytrd', 'r546', 'erdr', 'ewr4', 'ljty']]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать трюк с суммированием списков:

```
res = [sum([z.split() for z in x], []) for x in lst]
```

результат:

```
In [91]: res
Out[91]:
[['y58u', 'ufgh', 'ko9u', 'ffs5', 'dfdg'],
 ['rf32', 'sff4', 'sdfs', 're3d'],
 ['df31', 'ytrd', 'r546', 'erdr', 'ewr4', 'ljty']]
```

---

или немного подправить ваше решение:

```
res = [" ".join(x).split() for x in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

Я нашла ответ:

```
x = ' '.join(text)
x.split()
```

Но у кого-то мб есть лучше идея.